# How to handle Objects and Variables that are universally needed in PHP

Tags: php, oop, global

So I've got a class for the caching system, a class for database connections, an array of app settings, a class for handling different languages, etc. These classes are all needed in most other classes I create

Is there a better way to handle it than to do this:

```
function __construct($database,$cache,$appsettings,$language,...) {
```

in every class I have? Another problem with this approach is that I can't make functions static if they need a database connection. So for example, I have a users class that right now has a "getUsernameFromID()" function, which uses the database to get that username. If I use the above approach, I would have to actually create a user class, every time some piece of code needs a username from an ID.

Singleton classes would be a solution to this, but other answers on here say that they are a bad practice in PHP. Right now I'm using globals for these classes, which is obviously a bad solution as well. What should I do?

I hope that was clear enough, I'm doing my best.

Comment: Autoloaders? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: You could create one `ApplicationState` class, which contains the state of the current application, and has objects for cache, the database, etc. Then you would only have to inject an `ApplicationState` instance into your classes, and if you need the database, you could just pull it from the state: `state.getDatabase();`

Comment: Depends entirely on your existing architecture. If you are lamenting the loss of static functions, then chances are your architecture is not well designed. If you are stuck with what you have, a singleton wrapper seems the best option. If not, take a look at how other popular, modern mvc frameworks approach this

Comment: I'm just getting started with OOP in PHP, so I don't have much experience. What are some popular MVCs I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into the Dependency Injection and Service Locator design patterns. [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) is a popular dependency injection manager.

Singletons aren't necessarily a bad practice. Many times we just use them badly. For example, a class that manages it's own "single-ness" can be considered an anti-pattern. It creates a dependency on itself and enforces that globally (outside it's own scope). It's better that the single-ness be managed by the framework or other object that can enforce it within a scope.